# C Using a variable stored in char

Tags: c, char

```
int main()
{
    float S = 7.5, R = 5.85, D = 5.95, liters, price;
    char answer;
    printf("Choose one of the following fuels or X to quit:\nS - gas 98 \nR - gas 95\nD - diesel fuel\n");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    switch (answer)
    {
        case 'S': case 's':
            printf("You selected to fuel with gas 98\n");
            break;
        case 'R': case 'r':
            printf("You selected to fuel with gas 95\n");
            break;
        case 'D': case 'd':
            printf("You selected to fuel with disel fuel\n");
            break;
        case 'X': case 'x':
            printf("Thank you.\n");
            break;
}
    printf("The price list is:\ngas98 - 7.5 NIS\ngas98 - 5.85 NIS\ndiesel - 5.95 NIS\n");
    printf("How much liters would you like to fuel?\n");
    scanf("%f", &liters);
    price = answer * liters;
    printf("You choose to fuel %0.0f\nThe price is:%0.0f\n", liters, price);
    return 0;
}
```

Hello guys, 
As you can see i'm trying to get the program to tell the costumer the price of his purchase (`price = answer * liters`). In answer there's a stored letter he entered (`R`, `S`, `D`). Isn't it supposed to use the value I declared it as a float variable?
because i get a wrong value when i do answer * liters, ie: the costumer choose 100 liters, and S, the answer should be 750 (100 * 7.5), but it isn't.

Im realy new to c or any other programing language.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is it just me?

Comment: @EugeneSh.- It seems OP does not understand what this code does.

Comment: `'S'` is not `S`. The former is an object of type `char`, the latter a variable of type `float`.

Comment: You do not use your float variables in your code.

Comment: You must set the price in each case statement, and multiply by that instead of the menu keyboard entry. And BTW your price list duplicates fuel type (98 is twice).

Comment: This is minor compared to the rest, but it is better to use `f` suffix in `float` literals, e.g. `float S = 7.5f`.

Comment: And then of course there's that whole "floats are bad for financial calculations" topic, even though this may be irrelevant in the context of this example.

Comment: You should not use variable names with more than 1 character. Or function names, or... That way you will never use more than 53 variables and functions. And you ensure no one else wants to read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like this... `answer` contains a value that cannot be used so simply to denote another variable by its name. What you can do is to assign the base price in your switch like this, and use it further to compute you final price:

```
int main()
{
    float liters, price, basePrice;
    char answer;
    printf("Choose one of the following fuels or X to quit:\nS - gas 98 \nR - gas 95\nD - diesel fuel\n");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    switch (answer)
    {
        case 'S': case 's':
            printf("You selected to fuel with gas 98\n");
            basePrice = 7.5;
            break;
        case 'R': case 'r':
            printf("You selected to fuel with gas 95\n");
            basePrice = 5.85;
            break;
        case 'D': case 'd':
            printf("You selected to fuel with disel fuel\n");
            basePrice = 5.95;
            break;
        case 'X': case 'x':
            printf("Thank you.\n");
            return 0;
    }
    printf("The price list is:\ngas98 - 7.5 NIS\ngas98 - 5.85 NIS\ndiesel - 5.95 NIS\n");
    printf("How much liters would you like to fuel?\n");
    scanf("%f", &liters);
    price = basePrice * liters;
    printf("You choose to fuel %0.0f\nThe price is:%0.0f\n", liters, price);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `case 'X': ... return 0;`

Comment: `default: ... return 0;`

Comment: `default: return main(); /* muahaha!! */`

Answer (score 0):

Characters are not variables. You have to set a flag or something in cases.

```
float SelectedThing;

case 'S':
-----
SelectedThing = S;

price = SelectedThing * liters;
```

Answer (score 0):

`answer` is not a `float`, it is a `char` that contains a letter like `'S'`.

There is also a variable, `S`, but that has nothing to do with `answer`. One way to do this is to decide, in your `case` statement, which price to use and save that in a `float` called, perhaps, `selectedPrice`. Then multiply that by the number of liters.

Note that a `char` value can be treated as a number. For example, you can multiply `'S' * 10`, which works because C will treat the `char` as equivalent to its ASCII value. `'S'` is 83 in ASCII, so typing “S” then choosing 10 liters would give 830. Not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

in your statement `price = answer * liters;` you multiply `char` by `float` which will not result in what you expect.what you need to do is in the `switch` statement assign a `float` variable the value of S,R,or D, according to the choice

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float S = 7.5, R = 5.85, D = 5.95, liters, price;
    //note here
    float ANS;

    char answer;
    printf("Choose one of the following fuels or X to quit:\nS - gas 98 \nR - gas 95\nD - diesel fuel\n");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    switch (answer)
    {
        case 'S' : case 's':
            printf("You selected to fuel with gas 98\n");
            ANS = S;
            break;
        case 'R': case 'r':
            printf("You selected to fuel with gas 95\n");
            ANS = R;
            break;
        case 'D': case 'd':
            printf("You selected to fuel with disel fuel\n");
            ANS = D;
            break;
        case 'X': case 'x':
            printf("Thank you.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    printf("The price list is:\ngas98 - 7.5 NIS\ngas98 - 5.85 NIS\ndiesel - 5.95 NIS\n");
    printf("How much liters would you like to fuel?\n");
    scanf("%f", &liters);
    //note here
    price = ANS * liters;
    printf("You choose to fuel %0.0f\nThe price is:%0.0f\n", liters, price);
    return 0;
}
```